# Sort Date stored in SQLite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, date, datetime

I'm using a SQLite database (not mine) and I have to sort some data, order by date.

I have done many searches on the web but no solutions found!
The type of the field with the dates is "Date", with the format: `DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:SS`

I tried many functions like strftime, datetime, date, ... But I can't sort the date correctly.
For example, if I do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY start_date
```

The date 04/10/2013 00:00:00 is after 03/12/2013... You know what I mean ?

I really don't know how I can sort in this format.

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT start_date FROM events ORDER BY strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', start_date)
```

Is this the right way to do ? 
Results: No error, but nothing has changed. The dates are not sorted.

**UPDATE 2:**

Solution by laalto:

```
select * from tab order by substr(col,7,4)||'-'||substr(col,4,2)||'-'||substr(col,1,2)||'T'||substr(col,12);
```

Comment: Have a look at the STRFTIME() function which enables you to select a specific part of the date (hour, full date, time etc) and then order by that. not sure why yours isnt working though. EG. - SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY strftime('%s', start_date)

Comment: Thank you Steven, I look right now ;)

Comment: You may want to check the date format? Is it in mm/dd/yyy? If yes then whatever you are getting is right. I don't think you need to use date functions to order by date column

Comment: @IndoKnight No, the format is dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to make the data sortable at insertion phase e.g. by inserting ISO-8601 stamps or unixtime integers, but since it's not your database, let's assume you can't influence that.

You can use `substr()` to extract parts from the datetime string and construct e.g. a ISO-8601 datetime string that you can sort lexicographically, resulting in chronological order.

Example:

```
sqlite> create table tab(col);
sqlite> insert into tab values('04/10/2013 00:00:00'),('03/12/2013 00:00:00');
sqlite> select substr(col,7,4)||'-'||substr(col,4,2)||'-'||substr(col,1,2)||'T'||substr(col,12) as date from tab order by date;
2013-10-04T00:00:00
2013-12-03T00:00:00
sqlite> select * from tab order by substr(col,7,4)||'-'||substr(col,4,2)||'-'||substr(col,1,2)||'T'||substr(col,12);
04/10/2013 00:00:00
03/12/2013 00:00:00
```